# How to redirect to a different domain EXCEPT when url matches certain patterns

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following rule in my .htaccess file that should redirect a request like this:

http://www.olddomain.com/some/url/ -> http://www.newdomain.com/some/url/

unless the path matches something like /images/someimage.jpg

There's a few exceptions like this, built into the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!images/.*|css/.*|js/.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is behaving as expected when I test using http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

But, on the live server, $1 is never set. Urls that match the pattern are just redirected to the home page "/"

This is the very first rule of my htaccess file, after `RewriteEngine On`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your rule with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/((images|css|js)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work - any ideas why my attempt didn't work? seems like something not wrong with the regex, but something that's not right (by design or not) - with the way mod-rewrite does it's thing.

Comment: Your code actually didn't even capture `$1`. Most likely `RewriteRule ^(?!(?:images|css|js)/)(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]` would have worked.

Comment: Tip: That test site is not very unreliable. You should always test using your own web server.